# Duplicate keys OK when nested in JSON

Tags: json

Consider a JSON representation for delivering a package from one address to another. Simplified,

```
{
    "parcelId": 123,
    "source": {
        "street": "123 Main Street",
        "city": "Anytown",
        "state": "New York"
    },
    "destination": {
        "street": "456 Avenue B",
        "city": "Elsewhere",
        "state": "New Jersey"
    }
}
```

I'm fairly sure that keys "street", "city", and "state" *can* be legally nested in both "source" and "destination" objects. Are there technical reasons that the key names should *not* be repeated?

Comment: Short: No. What makes you doubt that you can reuse the keys in separate parts of the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there technical reasons that the key names should not be repeated?

No. Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

e.g. if I was serialising a Scala/Java object, that object could look like:

```
class Delivery {
  val parcelId : String
  val source : Address
  val destination : Address
}
```

and the *field names* of the `Address` object would be the same here.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having duplicate property keys which are part of different objects in JSON.

Your JSON example is perfectly valid.

---

This is only an issue when they are at the same level.

For example two `source` objects:

```
{
    "parcelId": 123,
    "source": {
        "street": "123 Main Street",
        "city": "Anytown",
        "state": "New York"
    },
    "source": {
        "street": "456 Avenue B",
        "city": "Elsewhere",
        "state": "New Jersey"
    }
}
```

Or two `street` properties inside one object:

```
    "source": {
        "street": "456 Avenue B",
        "street": "Elsewhere",
        "state": "New Jersey"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. This would be confusing if you had `delivery.street` and then a different `delivery.street`. But you don't. You have `delivery.source.street` and `delivery.destination.street`. Basically the key `street` is addressing a completely different object now.